# php a href post isset

Tags: php, post

```
<?php echo isset($_GET["name"])?$_GET['name']:'ddd'; ?>
<?php   
... 
$url = ("http://localhost/web12/directory/list=".$_GET['name']."");
//echo $url;
...
?>
<form action="t.php" method="post" target="_self">
    <a href="t.php?name=aaa">aaa</a>
    <a href="t.php?name=bbb">bbb</a>
    <a href="t.php?name=ccc">ccc</a>
</form>
```

How do I make it so that if the post is empty(first time open the t.php),let the `$url = ("http://localhost/web12/directory/list=ddd");` ?

Now my default `$_GET['name']` echoes nothing.`$url =("http://localhost/web12/directory/list=")` Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several issues here.

Try not to use ternaries if you can get away with it. They're just hard to read, and can be confusing. This is of course my own opinion. Also, I check with strlen() instead of isset, as I have had issues with isset() and arrays.

```
<?php

if (strlen($_GET["name"]) > 0) {
    $urlname = $_GET['name'];
    echo "GET: $urlname";
} elseif (strlen($_POST["name"]) > 0) {
    $urlname = $_POST['name'];
    echo "POST: $urlname";
} else {
    $urlname = 'ddd';
    echo "NONE: $urlname";
}

?>
```

You don't need the parentheses around a string declaration.

```
<?php

$url = "http://localhost/web12/directory/list=".$urlname;
echo $url;

?>
```

Forms get or post data only by submitting information, where anchor (a) tags send information through get (the query string after the filename). So you're mixing these without getting the effect you want.

**GET**

Will send information through the query string (like a link):

```
<form action="t.php" method="get" target="_self">
 <input type="radio" name="name" value="aaa"/> AAA<br/>
 <input type="radio" name="name" value="bbb"/> BBB<br/>
 <input type="radio" name="name" value="ccc"/> CCC
 <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Note the submit button.

**POST**

Will submit as post information, without affecting the action url:

```
<form action="t.php" method="post" target="_self">
 <input type="radio" name="name" value="aaa"/> AAA<br/>
 <input type="radio" name="name" value="bbb"/> BBB<br/>
 <input type="radio" name="name" value="ccc"/> CCC
 <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Note the submit button.

**ANCHOR GET**

Links do not fire the form submit, no matter if they are within a form element or outside of one. They're just not part of the form submit process.

```
<a href="t.php?name=aaa">aaa</a>
<a href="t.php?name=bbb">bbb</a>
<a href="t.php?name=ccc">ccc</a>
```

Comment: woo~~ sevral method, it is a great answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
$variable = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : 'ddd'; 
... 
$url = "http://localhost/web12/directory/list=" . $variable;
```

Comment: It was more than just the GET/POST too.  Your $url value would NEVER have had "ddd" in it as the default, it would always have been blank because it was looking for the value of $_GET['name']

Comment: Also, you wouldn't get anything from that "form" as they are simply links and need to be something like  <input type='text' name='name'>

Answer (score 1):

The quick and dirty method would be the

```
<?
$val = $_POST['val'];
if (!$_POST) {
 // No posted data, so do something else
 $val = 'Default val';
}
?>
```

Also, you form have method="POST", which will be captured by $_POST, not $_GEt

Comment: Not recommended since this will generated undefined key notices if $_POST['val'] is not set. The OP had the correct approach, just needed to replace $_GET with $_POST

Comment: True :] as said, it was quick and dirty

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest way

```
<?php

$name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'name');
if (!$name) $name = 'ddd';

$url = 'http://localhost/web12/directory/list=' . urlencode($name);
```